# Velocity: code fails to run inside Velocimacro

Tags: velocity

I've written the following code in the HTML of a Velocity page:

```
#foreach($element in $myList)
<tr>
    <td class="line1 color2">$element[0]</td>
    <td class="line1">$element[1]</td>
    <td class="line1">$element[2]</td>
    <td class="line1">$element[3]</td>
</tr>
#end
```

It works fine, but once I put this inside a macro (by appending a `#macro (myTable)` before the first line and a `#end` after the last), it stops printing anything.

Is there anything special about velocimacros I'm not aware of? How can I debug what's going on?

Comment: Did you actually call the macro after defining it?

Comment: Yes, I have a `#myTable()` in my HTML. Also, I forgot to mention that another macro I defined in this same page works fine - but it just changes a variable value, without actually "printing" anything. Does this make a difference?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Can you paste the actual code that you have?